# DataBricks Spark Delta Table Authentication Issues on Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We are trying to execute databricks notebook in azure Data factory, when we execute in notebook to call the spark.table("table path"), the dataframe and notebook executed perfectly. if we are trying to use ADF to trigger databriks notebook, we are getting as below kind of error, kindly help.

code : `spark.table("table path and name")`

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: HTTP Error 401;
> url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/32131312/oauth2/token'
> AADToken: HTTP connection to
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/3212312312/oauth2/token failed for
> getting token from AzureAD.; requestId='32131231312-3123123-80300';
> contentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'; response
> '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid
> client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is
> the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added
> to app '[REDACTED]'.\r\nTrace ID:
> 854dadaDAdafb4-4d4d-48eeeedddded-89fc-b841eee80000\r\nCorrelation ID:
> asdasda-dc4f-4739-bf08-dsadasdasda\r\nTimestamp: 2023-07-27
> 09:26:03Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2023-07-27
> 09:26:03Z","trace_id":"asdsadadas-4d4d-48ed-89fc-xccsasad80300","correlation_id":"asdsadsad-dc4f-4739-bf08-ddc0a0e4529a","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}'shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException:
> HTTP Error 401;
> url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdsadasdasd/oauth2/token'
> AADToken: HTTP connection to
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/0002cd24-7dd6-4542-acd6-e0cjhjhh/oauth2/token
> failed for getting token from AzureAD.;
> requestId='854bdfb4-4d4d-48ed-89fc-8989899';
> contentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'; response
> '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid
> client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is
> the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added
> to app '[REDACTED]'.\r\nTrace ID:
> 854bdfb4-4d4d-48ed-89fc-sdadasdsad\r\nCorrelation ID:
> c5d43820-dc4f-4739-bf08-ddc0a0e4529a\r\nTimestamp: 2023-07-27
> 09:26:03Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2023-07-27
> 09:26:03Z","trace_id":"854bdfb4-4d4d-48ed-89fc-sadsasad","correlation_id":"dasdasdasdas-dc4f-4739-bf08-ddc0a0e4529a","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}'

Comment: Where is the error coming from? ADF or databricks? Is the databricks notebook being triggered at all? Can you edit the question with your code and a snapshot of the linked service? I would like to see what kind of authentication are you using to trigger the notebook

Comment: its ADF side throwing error and linked service simply created ADB connection...

Comment: What authentication are you using ? How are you creating the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [access token](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=96a1bbdcc8ec9cabJmltdHM9MTY5MDg0ODAwMCZpZ3VpZD0yNzdiMDY4YS1kNmVmLTYwN2ItMmE0MS0xNDgxZDJlZjZlMzMmaW5zaWQ9NTQ4OA&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=277b068a-d6ef-607b-2a41-1481d2ef6e33&psq=generate+access+token+in+databricks&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWFybi5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2VuLXVzL2F6dXJlL2RhdGFicmlja3MvZGV2LXRvb2xzL2F1dGgjOn46dGV4dD1UbyUyMGNyZWF0ZSUyMGFuJTIwQXp1cmUlMjBEYXRhYnJpY2tzJTIwcGVyc29uYWwlMjBhY2Nlc3MlMjB0b2tlbixDb3B5JTIwdGhlJTIwZGlzcGxheWVkJTIwdG9rZW4lMkMlMjBhbmQlMjB0aGVuJTIwY2xpY2slMjBEb25lLg&ntb=1) authentication in ADF for data bricks notebook.

Databricks notebook:

[image]

Create the linked service as mentioned below:

[image]

You can set above linked service for databricks notebook activity and browse the notebook. It will run successfully without any error:

[image]